# In C++11, can I implement an aggregate-type-initialization like constructor for an non-aggregate type, and how?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Say, I have a 1-dimensional array encapsulated in a class named `stA`

```
class stA
{
public:
    template<typename ... T>
    stA(T ... t):
        data_{t...}
    {}

private:
    int data_[2];
};
```

By taking advantage of *variadic template*, I can succeed in implementing this idea.

```
stA a = {1, 2};
```

But, when I tried to bring this trick to 2-dimensional-like class named `stB`,

```
class stB
{
public:
    template<typename ... T>
    stB(T ... t):
        data_{t...}
    {}

private:
    stA data_[2];
};
```

the trick failed.

```
stB b = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}};
```

> error: could not convert '{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}' from brace-enclosed
>   initializer list to 'stB'
>        stB b = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}};

And this quite confuses to me at beginning.

Because if *template-argument-deduction* in `stB::Ctor` results in `T = const stA &`, then the `Ctor` would become something like this,

```
stB(const stA & a, const stA & b):
        data_{a, b}
    {}
```

and of course `stB b = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}};` would survive but with losing some flexibility in arguments.

After I had done some searching, I finally realized this may violate a rule of *template argument deduction*,

> Non-deduced contexts
>
> 6) The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not
>   std::initializer_list, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or
>   a reference to an array:

But I'm still wandering
**Is there still a way to get this idea happened and how?**

Comment: That's because `{1, 2}` is not an expression and only expressions can be deduced .

Comment: Is *braced-init-list* not an expression?@L.F.

Comment: No, a *braced-init-list* is not an *expression*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `{1, 2}` is not an expression and only expressions can be deduced.

Option 1: use aggregate initialization.  Make the `data_` member public and aggregate initialization allows you to initialize the elements.  Drawback: little control.

Option 2: use `initializer_list`.  As in:

```
class stA {
public:
    stA(std::initializer_list<int> init):
        data_{init.begin()[0], init.begin()[1]}
    {
        assert(init.size() == 2);
    }

private:
    int data_[2];
};

class stB {
public:
    stB(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> init):
        data_{init.begin()[0], init.begin()[1]}
    {
        assert(init.size() == 2);
    }

private:
    stA data_[2];
};
```

Drawback: the size information is lost at compile time.

Option 3: use an aggregate type as constructor parameter.

```
class stA {
public:
    stA(const int (&arr)[2]):
        data_{arr[0], arr[1]}
    {
    }

private:
    int data_[2];
};

class stB {
public:
    stB(const int (&arr)[2][2]):
        data_{arr[0], arr[1]}
    {
    }

private:
    stA data_[2];
};
```

(This requires an extra pair of braces, as in `stB b = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};`.)